# Android Studio: logcat says null reference but I don´t see why?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, logcat

So I have 2 java classes, the main one being intents.java and the second one being BrowserView.java

I´ve declared both on the android manifest and added the permissions as well.

The main XML file is called main_linearlayout

Can anyone spot the error?

Thank you!

Also - the search button seems to be doing nothing when clicked, not quite sure why?

intents.java:

```
package com.course.example;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class intents extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
private EditText checkAmount, numOfPeople;
private double tip = 0.15;
private TextView viewBill, viewPerson, viewTip;
double totalB, totalP, totalTP, totalT;

// just in case:
//set a request code number to identify a particular request
public static final int requestCode_235 = 235;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setTheme(android.R.style.Theme_Dialog);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_linearlayout);

    // Set up click listeners for all the buttons
   // Button continueButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.first_button);
    //continueButton.setOnClickListener(this);

    Button goButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnGo);
    goButton.setOnClickListener(this);

    Button searchButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSearch);
    searchButton.setOnClickListener(this);

    Button mapButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnMap);
    mapButton.setOnClickListener(this);

    Button dialButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnDial);
    dialButton.setOnClickListener(this);

}



//avoids runtime check for permission to CALL_PHONE
public void onClick(View v)  {
    switch (v.getId()) {

        // 1) get the calculations
        case R.id.btnGo:
            // get info from text box called checkAmount:
            checkAmount = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.checkAmount);
            String checkString = checkAmount.getText().toString();
            double checkAmountD = Double.parseDouble(checkString);
            double checkAmountR = Math.round(checkAmountD * 100.0) / 100.0;

            // get info from number of people
            numOfPeople = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.numOfPeople);
            String numPeopleS = numOfPeople.getText().toString();
            double numPeopleD = Double.parseDouble(numPeopleS);

            // calculate total tip, total bill, total per person, and total tip per person
            totalT = checkAmountR  * tip;
            totalB = checkAmountR + totalT;
            totalP = totalB / numPeopleD;
            totalTP = totalT / numPeopleD;
            setNewText();           // print out calculations on app! :)
            break;


        //2) implicit intent, open dialer and make call
        case R.id.btnSearch:
            Intent i1 = new Intent(this, BrowserView.class);
            startActivityForResult(i1, requestCode_235);
            //startActivity(i1);
            break;

        //3) implicit intent, call GoogleMaps
        case R.id.btnMap:

            Uri uri2 = Uri.parse("geo:42.3889167,-71.2208033?z=18");

            Intent i2 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,uri2);

            if (i2.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                startActivity(i2);
            }
            break;

        //4) implicit intent, open dialer and make call
        case R.id.btnDial:
            Uri uri3 = Uri.parse("tel:7818912000");
            Intent i3 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL,uri3);
            startActivity(i3);
            break;

    }
}

public void setNewText(){
    // print these 4 out on the edit texts
    TextView viewBill = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.totalBill);
    double totalBRounded = Math.round(totalB * 100.0) / 100.0;
    String totalBillS = String.valueOf(totalBRounded);   // before rounding this was valueof(totalB)
    viewBill.setText("$" + totalBillS);

    TextView viewPerson = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.totalPerPerson);
    double totalPRounded = Math.round(totalP * 100.0) / 100.0;
    String totalPerPS = String.valueOf(totalPRounded);
    viewPerson.setText("$" + totalPerPS);

    TextView viewTip = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.totalTip);
    double totalTipRounded = Math.round(totalT * 100.0) / 100.0;
    String totalTipS = String.valueOf(totalTipRounded);
    viewTip.setText("$" + totalTipS);

    TextView viewTipPerPerson = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tipPerPerson);
    double totalTipPerPRounded = Math.round(totalTP * 100.0) / 100.0;
    String tipPerPersonS = String.valueOf(totalTipPerPRounded);
    viewTipPerPerson.setText("$" + tipPerPersonS);
}


//listen for event of requested activity finishing
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode,
                                int resultCode,  Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    switch (requestCode){
        case (requestCode_235): {

            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)
                Toast.makeText(this, "WebLookup finished", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            else
                Toast.makeText(this, "WebLookup is NOT working", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            break;
        }

        default : Toast.makeText(this, "", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }//switch

}// onActivityResult
```

`}`

browser view. java:

```
package com.course.example;
        import android.app.Activity;
        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.view.KeyEvent;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
        import android.view.View.OnKeyListener;
        import android.webkit.WebView;
        import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
        import android.widget.Button;
        import android.widget.EditText;

public class BrowserView extends Activity {
private EditText urlText;
private Button searchButton;
private WebView webView;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // ...
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.screen2);

    // Get a handle to all user interface elements
    urlText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.url_field);
    searchButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSearch);
    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web_view);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    //intercept URL loading and load in widget
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url){
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    });

    // Set button to open browser
    searchButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            webView.loadUrl(urlText.getText().toString());
        }
    });

    //set listener on EditText
    urlText.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
        public boolean onKey(View view, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {
                webView.loadUrl(urlText.getText().toString());
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
}

//the back key navigates back to the previous web page - we were looking at this
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && webView.canGoBack()) {
        webView.goBack();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

`}`

first couple of lines of logcat:

```
21-02-27 08:10:35.387 2853-2853/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.course.example, PID: 2853
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.course.example/com.course.example.intents}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3449)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
    at com.course.example.intents.onCreate(intents.java:49)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8000)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7984)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3422)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947) 
2021-02-27 08:11:23.928 5064-5064/com.course.example E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.course.example, PID: 5064
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.course.example/com.course.example.intents}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3449)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
        at com.course.example.intents.onCreate(intents.java:49)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8000)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7984)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3422)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947) 
2021-02-27 08:11:27.268 5101-5101/com.course.example E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.course.example, PID: 5101
```

Edit: here are the 2 XML files:

main linear layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/myLinearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ACA6AA"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="4dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/labelUserName"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:background="#F688B4"
        android:fontFamily="@font/alfa_slab_one"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Tip Calculator"
        android:textColor="#CCCECE"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"></TextView>



    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:background="#F688B4"
            android:fontFamily="serif-monospace"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Check Amount"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/checkAmount"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:textSize="18sp" >
        </EditText>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:background="#F688B4"
            android:fontFamily="serif-monospace"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Number of People"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/numOfPeople"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:textSize="18sp" >
        </EditText>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:background="#F688B4"
            android:fontFamily="serif-monospace"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Tip Percentage%"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/tipPercent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:textSize="18sp" >
        </EditText>

    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnGo"
            style="@style/demoStyle"
            android:text="Tip"></Button>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnWeb"
            style="@style/demoStyle"
            android:text="WEB"></Button>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnDial"
            style="@style/demoStyle"
            android:text="DIAL"></Button>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnMap"
            style="@style/demoStyle"
            android:text="MAP"></Button>


    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:background="#F688B4"
            android:fontFamily="@font/abhaya_libre"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Total Bill"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/totalBill"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:fontFamily="@font/abhaya_libre"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="16sp" />
    </LinearLayout>



    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:background="#F688B4"
        android:fontFamily="@font/abhaya_libre"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Total per Person"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/totalPerPerson"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:fontFamily="@font/abhaya_libre"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="16sp" />
</LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:background="#F688B4"
            android:fontFamily="@font/abhaya_libre"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Total Tip"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/totalTip"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:fontFamily="@font/abhaya_libre"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="16sp" />
    </LinearLayout>



    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:background="#F688B4"
            android:fontFamily="@font/abhaya_libre"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Tip per Person"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tipPerPerson"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:fontFamily="@font/abhaya_libre"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="16sp" />
    </LinearLayout>



</LinearLayout>
```

screen 2:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/url_field"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="4" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSearch"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="search" />
</LinearLayout>

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/web_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="#ACA6AA"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: please post relevant layout files, `screen2` and `main_linearlayout`

Comment: check your layout and your view id . it seems that they are not match in this line.searchButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSearch);

Comment: @a_local_nobody just added it! :)

Comment: do you see anything called `btnSearch` in your main layout ? (findview doesn't _find_ the view, it's null, app crashes)

Comment: @a_local_nobody ohh, you're right! can't believe i missed this, thank you!

Comment: @a_local_nobody do you happen to spot a reason why the "search" button in the second screen might not be working?

Answer (score -1):

The problem is you set the `onClickListener` on the `button` by `setOnClickListener` and you don't implement `view.onClickListener`.
you made a method with parameter of `View` and you don't have any `onclick` attribute on your `xml`.
either implement `view.onclicklistener` and have `setonclicklistener` or set attribute and have that method.
this should work properly
and also for your search button too if you are adding `onclicklistener` on `button` with that method you should use `new View.OnClickListener` the plain `onclicklistener` shall not work

Comment: no, in `main_linearlayout` there isn't anything in the xml with the ID `btnSearch`  so findViewById should return null. it doesn't matter how you set the click listener if findView returns null

Comment: maybe try to make the buttons a class field do the work